# Django - column contains list of objects

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, many-to-many

I'm looking for a way to store rows from another table in a table. I have a model called `Languages` and model called `Freelancers`. The thing I want is to store which languages the freelancer work with.

I think that if there were relationship `Many to One`, there would be just `language = models.ForeignKey(Languages)`. The problem is that the one freelancer could know more than one languages.

**Here are those models:**

```
class Languages(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language_shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    price_per_word = models.FloatField()

class Freelancers(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # languages = models.ForeignKey(Languages) # This is incorrect
    # languages = list(models.ForeignKey....) # I'm looking for something like this...
```

Since I'm new to Django I appreciate any advices.

Comment: The relationship they'd use is a many to many, many freelancers could work on a language, and one freelancer would work with many languages (Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for)

Comment: @Sayse Yes. So what would you do with the Freelancers table to make that relation Many to Many?

Answer (score 4):

This is the exact use case for a many-to-many relationship, which in Django is expressed by a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield):

```
languages = models.ManyToManyField(Languages)
```

Now for each freelancer you can do `freelancer.languages.all()` and for each language you can do `language.freelancers_set.all()`.

Note that in Django it is usual to use singular names for models: Freelancer and Language - because each instance refers to a single one.

Comment: There is also the option of a related name :)